# Interface structure in Typescript for object of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, interface, typescript-generics

The structure of JSON that is received from the server is something like this(I changed details):

```
{
  "apple": {
    "fruitName": "apple",
    "types": {
      "greenApple": {
        "productCode": "P1",
        "productName": "Green Apple",
        "color": "green",
      },
      "galaApple": {
        "productCode": "P2",
        "productName": "Gala Apple",
        "color": "light red",
      },
      "redDelicious": {
        "productCode": "P3",
        "productName": "Red delicious apple",
        "color": "bright red",
      }
    }
  },
  "orange": {
    "fruitName": "orange",
    "types": {
      "mandarin": {
        "productCode": "P5",
        "productName": "Mandarin Oranges",
        "color": "orange",
      },
      "bloodOrange": {
        "productCode": "P6",
        "productName": "Blood Orange",
        "color": "red",
      }
    }
  },
}
```

I am coming up with an Interface structure using Typescript for my project.

So far I have come up with this:

```
export type FruitTypes = {
  [key: string]: Product,
}

export type Product = {
  productCode: string
  productName: string
  color: string
}

export type Fruits = {
  fruitName: string
  type: object<FruitTypes>
}
```

What I am not understanding is how to make a declaration in Fruits for type?
`type: object<FruitTypes>` is not working.  It is going to be an object of objects. How do we describe this in Typescript.

Comment: Would it not just be `type: FruitTypes`?

Comment: @Taplar Its an object of objects. i am not sure if it would work.

Comment: Lots of things are objects of objects.  That's what most objects are.  Things with key value pairs, some of which have values that are objects.  I'm not sure I understand the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer to use [Record<K,T>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt)

```
export type Fruits = Record<string, FruitTypes>;

export type FruitTypes = {
  fruitName: string;
  types: Record<string, Product>;
}

export type Product = {
  productCode: string;
  productName: string;
  color: string;
}
```

or you can write it explicit

```
export type Fruits = {
  [key:string]: FruitTypes;
}

export type FruitTypes = {
  fruitName: string;
  types: {
    [key:string]: Product;
  };
}

export type Product = {
  productCode: string;
  productName: string;
  color: string;
}
```

Where `Fruits` is the type for the whole construct.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks